# Circuit understanding about the amplifier with a MG811 CO2 sensor

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, sensor, comparator

I am working on a project similar to [this post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/39360/amplifying-signal-from-co2-sensor/). 
For the circuit diagram on that post, what are the function and working principle of the upper amplifier? 
I know that the lower amplifier is used to magnify the input signal from the CO2 sensor.
Thanks! 
[image: The design circuit copy from the other post]

Comment: The answer was in the module in section b. comparator,  you guys, you not even read the post of your question !

Comment: The reason you don't see the functionality is that the schematic is poorly drawn

Answer (score 3):

The upper opamp is being used as a voltage comparator with its reference voltage being supplied by R1.

The lower opamp has a non-inverting DC gain of 8.5, and when its output voltage is more positive than the voltage on U1-5, U1-7 will go low, turning Q1 OFF and allowing INPUT to float.

However, when U1-6 goes less positive than U1-5, U1-7 will go high, turning Q1 ON, which will pull INPUT down to Q1's Vce(sat), about 300 millivolts above ground, give or take.

Answer (score 2):

In that circuit, the upper OpAmp is taking an input reference voltage on its non-inverting input and the output from the lower opOpAmp on its inverting input.

This forms an [OpAmp Comparator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparator#Op-amp_voltage_comparator), with the Potentiometer setting the comparator's reference/threshold voltage.

Comment: A potentiometer is not a [**varistor**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varistor).

Comment: @EMFields Thank you, I mis-spoke. Answer corrected.